# How to modify ds_bootstrap_layouts templates to add more layouts?

Tags: bootstrap-theme

I'm using the [Display Suite Bootstrap Layouts](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds_bootstrap_layouts) module in Drupal 7, and I want to create additional layouts.

For example, I want the 4-4-4 stacked turned into a double 4-4-4 stacked. I know how to access the files and modify them, but it causes errors and it doesn't show up in the backend.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I add more layouts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement the following hook

```
function MODULENAME_ctools_plugin_directory($module, $plugin) {
  return 'plugins/' . $plugin;
}
```

You can change the name of the 'plugins' directory, but cannot change the following.

2. Next you create a folder inside the 'plugins' directory and call it 'layouts' <--don't change. Then place your custom layouts in that directory.
3. Your .inc file will look something like this

```
$plugin = array(
    'title' => t('LAYOUT TITLE'),
    'icon' => 'ICON.png',
    'css' => 'CSS_FILE.css',
    'theme' => 'NAME OF TEMPLATE FILE W/O .tpl.php'
    'panels' => array(
      'top' => t('Top'),
      'top_left' => t('Top Left Column'),
      'top_right' => t('Top Right Column'),
      'middle' => t('Middle'),
      'bottom' => t('Bottom')
  ),
);
```

5. Panels will automatically scan your layouts folder for new layouts. **DONT FORGET TO CLEAR THE CACHE**. Your new layout will appear in the 'Miscellaneous' section when selecting a layout for your panel.